# Why is interior decorating insulting in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, connotations

This dialog is from the movie *[The Mexican](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0236493/)*. [This clip on YouTube](https://youtu.be/I2AjeXpxmI4?t=1m41s) may help with the context.

> Samantha: I... know the kind of people in your business, OK?
>
> Winston: Yeah?
>
> Samantha: And to me, it seems that well, being gay isn't really
>   conducive to the environment.
>
> Winston: Like **I should be an interior decorator. That's insulting.**

Why is it insulting?

Comment: This question is about literary interpretation, not about learning English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Winston is insulted because Terry has in effect said that that as a gay man he's not suited to his violent profession.

He rejects the implication by sarcastically instancing 'interior decorator' as the sort of profession which her stereotype regards as suitable to gay men.